# Can 2N2222A transistor be used to replace a MJ2955 transistor?

Tags: voltage, transistors, dc, low-power, inverter

I have tried multiple times to make this circuit. But I have been using 2N2222A transistors instead of the ones in the circuit and the circuit is not working. Do I have to use the transistor in the circuit to make it work? (I am not playing with 220VAC as I have made my own transformer that only doubles the 12 volts). Also, do I need the resistors?

[image]

Comment: Is the magic smoke saying anything yet?\

Comment: What does that mean? (sorry I am new to this)

Comment: No. Nothing is happening at all.

Comment: The *magic smoke* is the active substance that gives any electronic component its characteristics. Once it escapes from the component (usually because you are not kind enough with your parts), the part cannot work any longer, and you can appreciate the fragrance of the smoke in the air...... Of course this is one of the favorite joke of Electrical Engineers: once you see or smell smoke coming out of a component, it means something has gone terribly awry! Obligatory EEVblog references: [EEVsmoke#1](https://youtu.be/U_QoWa6qXeo) and [EEVsmoke#2](https://youtu.be/SoeVNaz7KGc).

Comment: This circuit came up a couple of days ago in another "simple inverter" question, with two other essentially identical (apart from stupid mistakes) circuits. You have 2 problems : (1) if using NPN transistors, you'll have to reverse the polarity of the supply and (2) 2N2222 transistors are far too low power to be useful, something like 2N3055 would be better.  I support the idea of the low voltage (12-24V) transformer, very good idea for proving the design safely, provided it's properly designed.

Answer (score 4):

Even before going into a complete understanding of finding a replacement transistor it should be clear that a BIG transistor (TO3 housing) can not replaced by a SMALL transistor (TO18 housing)

Once you understand that you can go further.

1. Take the spec sheets of both transistors.
2. Compare the properties such as NPN/PNP, Pmax,Ic max, Vce max and Hfe, Housing

Make sure that the replacement transistor has at the same or higher ratings.

If you understand the working of a transistor then it is possible with some adjustments (sometimes a lot of work) to replace an PNP transistor with an NPN version.

Answer (score 3):

No you can't. The 2N2222A is NPN and the MJ2955 is PNP. In simple terms, the PNP transistor will conduct if it's base electrode is at a lower potential than the emitter. NPN is the other way around, it conducts if the base electrode is at a potential higher than the emitter. So they're behaving very differently.

For this simple circuit you could use about any standard PNP transistor that can handle the 12v (+ margin because of inductive load) and the 1A current (you're probably going to need a heatsink if you want to run this for more than a few seconds). You do need the resistors in order to limit the base current and stabilize the circuit. If you pick a different transistor, there's a chance you'll have to user other resistors, too.

edit: if you just want to build a simple AC-generator, there are other circuits that use NPN transistors. Also remember that a circuit as simple as the one you posted will never be giving you a 50Hz sine. The frequency depends on many characteristics of the transistors and even the wiring, so you shouldn't use something like this for anything other than a lamp, really.

Comment: The 2n2222's are not going to work but you can solve the pnp npn problem by reversing the DC input voltage leads.

Answer (score 0):

A 2955 is a LARGE, HIGH-POWER transistor capable of 15 Amps and 115 Watts.  A 2222 is a TINY, SMALL-SIGNAL transistor capable of 1/2 Amp and 1/2 Watt.  Using a 2N2222 in a circuit designed for a 2N2955 is like using a bicycle to haul a ton of freight. The bicycle would simply be crushed under the load before it even starts. And that is want is happening to your 2222 transistors.

Furthermore, you are trying to use NPN transistors in a circuit designed for PNP transistors. These are of OPPOSITE POLARITY and if you connect them as shown in your diagram you will INSTANTLY DESTROY the transistors from REVERSE POLARITY.

Yes, you need the transistors to limit the current going into the Base terminal of the transistors. If you omit those resistors, you will DESTROY them with over-current going into the Base.

It appears that you do not understand how transistors work well enough to attempt to build this circuit. Or at least not well enough to try to substitute components and/or modify the circuit.  This kind of high-power circuit is NOT the kind of circuit that is good for beginners to experiment with. Unless you have a huge box of transistors to destroy while you learn the hard way.

Comment: A little over the top, and indeed containing its own errors.